# What is Device-to-AP RTT

Tags: wifi, android-wifi

I was browsing through the Android Wifimanager class and I found this method:
`public boolean isDeviceToApRttSupported ()`

> Returns
>   true if this adapter supports Device-to-AP RTT

But what is Device-to-AP RTT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTT = round trip time
= time of a signal going from one device to the other and back

Judging just from the name of the method this should answer the question if measurment of rtt is possible (supported) or not.

speculative:
It's more likely that this answer is given for your android device and its wifi-hotspot feature and not for any remote devices that are connected.

Answer (score 6):

WiFi RTT (round-trip-time) is for indoor positioning, and is included in the Android P preview: https://developer.android.com/preview/features.html

> Android P adds platform support for the IEEE 802.11mc Wi-Fi
>   protocol—also known as Wi-Fi Round-Trip-Time (RTT)—to let you take
>   advantage of indoor positioning in your apps.
>
> On Android P devices with hardware support, your apps can use the new
>   RTT APIs to measure the distance to nearby Wi-Fi Access Points (APs).
>   The device must have location enabled and Wi-Fi turned on, and your
>   app must have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. The device doesn't
>   need to connect to the APs to use RTT. To maintain privacy, only the
>   phone is able to determine the distance to the AP; the APs do not have
>   this information.
>
> If your device knows the distance to 3 or more APs, the API uses a
>   multilateration algorithm to estimate the device position that best
>   fits those measurements. The result is typically accurate within 1 to
>   2 meters.
>
> With this accuracy, you can build new experiences like in-building
>   navigation, fine- grained location-based services such as
>   disambiguated voice control (for example, "Turn on this light"), and
>   location-based information (such as "Are there special offers for this
>   product?").

Comment: Do you have an idea how to write an example using it?

Comment: Why is RTT needed, cant WiFi signal strength in db be used as a measure of distance, over which we can use triangulation to get location?

Comment: Because lots of things affect signal strength besides distance. Walls, antenna orientation, how much your hand is blocking the antenna, etc. If someone walked between you and the AP, the signal strength would decrease, and your phone would suddenly think you had moved further away.